# Material Top Tabs Navigator not working with nested navigation

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to use material-top-tab-navigator with inside a Scrollview of Stack Navigator. But as you can see in the screenshot the individual screens of tab navigator is rendering nothing. How to solve it?

Thanks in advance :)

My tab navigator looks like this:

TabNavigator.js:

```
import {ScrollView, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createMaterialTopTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';

function FeedScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Feed!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function NotificationsScreen() {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: 500,
        width: 500,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
      }}>
      <Text>Notifications!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}


const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Feed"
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveTintColor: '#e91e63',
        tabBarLabelStyle: {fontSize: 12},
        tabBarStyle: {backgroundColor: 'powderblue'},
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Feed"
        component={FeedScreen}
        options={{tabBarLabel: 'Home'}}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Notifications"
        component={NotificationsScreen}
        options={{tabBarLabel: 'Updates'}}
      />
      
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function TabNavigator(props) {
  return (
    <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
      <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
        <MyTabs />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

The component in which I am using this tab navigator is as follows:

Screen.js:

```
import {
  ImageBackground,
  ScrollView,
  View,

} from 'react-native';
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
import {
  profileBackground,
  leftIcon,
} from '../../Assets/Image';
import {IconButton} from 'react-native-paper';
import TabNavigator from './TabNavigator';



export default function (props) {


  return (
    
      <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
        <ImageBackground style={{width: wp(100)}} source={profileBackground}>
          <IconButton
            icon={leftIcon}
            onPress={() => {
              props.navigation.goBack();
            }}
          />
          
        </ImageBackground>
        
        <View style={{marginTop: 20, marginHorizontal: 20}}>
          <TabNavigator />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Wrap the NavigationContainer with an View instead of an ScrollView

Comment: Thanks it worked, I had to give the view width and height explicitly. But, it is not working with flex:1 . What if my content in individual tabs gets more and more?

Comment: Put the scrollview within in tabs content view.

Comment: I'm facing same issue did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Add flex property for the wrapper container:

The property needs to be added in the contentContainerStyle prop instead of the style prop

```
<Scrollview contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution of @Abiranjan work perfectly for my case. I had to add ScrollView into my nested screen and also added

```js
<Scrollview contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}
```

to make it work

Answer (score 0):

adding the flex:1 style attribute to the  which surrounds the nested navigation <Tab.Navigator> fixed my issue. The top tab and the page it manages now shows up.